# Cointegration - different units, order of variables.

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, time-series

If two series $\{x_y\}$ and $\{y_t\}$ are not stationary but their a linear combination of them, say $u_t = \beta x_t - y_t$, is a stationary process, then we say $\{x_t\}$ and $\{y_t\}$ are cointegrated.

I have two questions.

1. If I want to check the cointegration of two series that do not have the same unit, e.g. sales data and exchange rates, do I have to normalize them, for example? I think yes.
2. How do I determine which variable should be multiplied by $\beta$ in the model? From what I observed, if I swap the order of the variables I get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quantity $X$, let $[X]$ denote its units. If $\beta$ is in front of $x_t$, then $[\beta] = \frac{[y_t]}{[x_t]}$, in which case the residual series has units $[y_t]$. If $\beta$ is instead in front of $y$, $[\beta] = \frac{[x_t]}{[y_t]}$ and so the residuals have unit $[x_t]$.

In either case, normalisation and the choice of which variable is regressed on which (assuming they are centred) does not matter, as your conclusion of whether they are co-integrated will be the same. That is, the residuals of the two regressions are either both stationary or both non-stationary.

Comment: What do you mean said "assuming they are centred"? By the way, thanks for answer.

Comment: @Szymon83 they have mean zero

Comment: I don't understand why the assumption is that they have mean equals zero.

Comment: @Szymon83 To simplify things; otherwise, you would have to estimate the mean of the residual process separately. This is not such a big constraint, as one usually looks at cointegration of returns, which aren't too far of from having mean zero.